# Reload Freeradius clients without restart the service

Tags: ubuntu, service, configuration, freeradius

Is there a way to reload the Freeradius clients configuration without restarting the service? I'm using:

- Ubuntu Server 12
- Freeradius 2.1.10
- MySQL v5.5.20 (I'm storing the clients in the "nas" table)

Answer (score 1):

Freeradius handles the HUP signal.

So, this should do the job:

> kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid)